# PHP regular expression to extract an integer from complex string

Tags: regex

```
$str = "<a href='#'>Page 10 | <span>Some more data</span></a>";
```

I want to extract the number after word Page. Its format will always be

`Page<space><integer value> |`

What will be the regular expression for it?

Comment: `Page\s+?(\d+)` will do it

Comment: please include the "|" as well

Comment: What is your regex flavour?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ No need in the lazy quantifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said the format is fixed, we can do a simple match with a capture group.

```
\bPage\s+(\d+)\s+\|
```

https://regex101.com/r/eI2kQ5/3

Comment: lease include the "|" as well